# Modifying PHP rand function

Tags: c, php-internals

For testing and learning purpose, I wanted to modify the php **rand** and **mt_rand** functions  which are in https://github.com/php/php-src:ext/standard/rand.c.

I wanted to give a fixed output each time rand function is called and for this purpose I modified the code

```
PHPAPI long php_rand(TSRMLS_D)
{
    long ret;

    if (!BG(rand_is_seeded)) {
        php_srand(GENERATE_SEED() TSRMLS_CC);
    }

#ifdef ZTS
    ret = php_rand_r(&BG(rand_seed));
#else
# if defined(HAVE_RANDOM)
    ret = random();
# elif defined(HAVE_LRAND48)
    ret = lrand48();
# else
    ret = rand();
# endif
#endif

    // ignoring the results coming from the calls above and 
    // returning a constant value 
    ret = 3264;

    return ret;
}
```

compiled

```
./configure
make
make install
```

and finally called the rand function as `echo rand(3000,4000);` and it always returns `3000`.

What would be the way to modify this function? and why there is `TSRMLS_D` but not the range parameters?

Comment: Tthis a c question not a php one.

Comment: @Dagon I missed that, thanks for correcting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual function that is called from PHP is the one declared [`PHP_FUNCTION(rand)`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/rand.c#L290), which calls the [`php_rand()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/rand.c#L63) function that you modified. It does the following:

```
PHP_FUNCTION(rand)
{
    long min;
    long max;
    long number;
    int  argc = ZEND_NUM_ARGS();

    if (argc != 0 && zend_parse_parameters(argc TSRMLS_CC, "ll", &min, &max) == FAILURE)
        return;

    number = php_rand(TSRMLS_C);
    if (argc == 2) {
        RAND_RANGE(number, min, max, PHP_RAND_MAX);
    }

    RETURN_LONG(number);
}
```

As you can see, if you pass 2 parameters in, it calls the [`RAND_RANGE`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/php_rand.h#L43) macro, which transforms the result of `php_rand()` into the range given.

```
#define RAND_RANGE(__n, __min, __max, __tmax) \
    (__n) = (__min) + (long) ((double) ( (double) (__max) - (__min) + 1.0) * ((__n) / ((__tmax) + 1.0)))
```

If you want it always to output a given value, I would recommend modifying `PHP_FUNCTION(rand)`, instead of `php_rand()`.

Though if all you're looking for is stable random number outputs, so that you get the same result every time, if you don't care about the exact result, you can just call [`srand(0)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php) at the beginning of your program, to seed the random number generator with a constant value. This will mean that the random number generator will always give you the same sequence of random numbers, which is useful for testing purposes, and can be done without patching PHP itself.

Comment: Thanks alot! I modified the PHP_FUNCTION(rand) and it worked. I will work on that function rather than php_rand.

Comment: Actually, the main reason of the modification is not to give fixed output, I wanted to test some stuff on rand and mt_rand. Fixed output was just to understand how things work.

Comment: @acidrous Fair enough, I figured that was probably the case, but wanted to make sure I included the comment about `srand()` in case that's the reason you were doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the RAND_RANGE macro define in php_rand.h. It does some additional permutation/scrambling of the input value to make it fit between the range you've specified.

If you really want the rand() function to return 3264 even if that doesn't fit within the parameters passed to rand(), remove this block in rand.c:

```
    if (argc == 2) {
    RAND_RANGE(number, min, max, PHP_RAND_MAX);
}
```

If you still want to consider min/max, you're going to need to figure out what you want that to actually do if you specify a min/max that doesn't include your hardcoded number.